# Android onClick for multiple classes

Tags: java, android, xml, class, onclick

I have an app that that switches the layout between the xml files quite smoothly. The problem lies in the force closes when I try to hit a button. I hate using the listeners as they bulk up the program too much so I use the onClick in xml. I made an entirely seperate java file for the second layout to organize it, but the onClick does not reference the second java file and force closes. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: What's the exception text in LogCat?

Comment: WARNING: Android will look for the onClick method only in the current Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code and exactly how you are doing it, this sounds like trouble. However, doing it in xml is fine and I do it quite often as I agree it seems to look nicer most of the time.

What you can do, if you have buttons that do the same action in several `Activities`, is to extend from a `BaseActivity` for your other `Activities`. Then you can use the same `onClick()` in different `Activities`.

For instance, I created my own "Action Bar" so it was more customized for my specific client-base. I made this my `layout` for my `BaseActivity`. So on the "Action Bar" is a back `Button`. I `<include>` this `layout` in my other `Activities` and extend this `BaseActivity` then the `Button` uses the functionality from the `BaseActivity`. I can override these `Button`s in certain `Activities` if I need different functionality.

I hope this helps. If not then please describe your problem a little better and provide some of the code you are using along with errors/logcat

Comment: Actually declaring onClick methods in XML is not recommended http://corner.squareup.com/2012/08/getting-to-the-bottom.html

Comment: @f2prateek Not recommended by who? Some guy that says there was a bug in Froyo? I have never seen where Google doesn't recommend it and works just fine for me every time. Read Jake Wharton's comment on the link you provided

Comment: If you read the article, that's exactly what it (Jesse) and Jake say, don't use it unless you you're using it on the appropriate API levels.
As for credibility, read up Jesse's profile.

Comment: Yes, so saying "Actually declaring onClick methods in XML is not recommended" is not an accurate statement

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not saying you're solution isn't wrong, just wanted to point out that declaring onClick methods in xml isn't always a good choice.

Comment: That's fine but you should clarify on certain API's then instead of a general statement. Because it is perfectly fine on Gingerbread and above